# Picasso Load Bitmap or byte[] to imageview

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm trying to find how can i load an image from byte or bitmap to imageview using picasso library.

Here is what i'm trying to do

```
 ImageView imageview1 = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.CategoryImageView);

 Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Image, 0, Image.Length);

 Picasso.With(mContext).Load((decodedByte)).Into(imageview1);
```

But i'm getting error can not convert android graphics bitmap to anroid net uri
Also here is what i'm trying for byte[]

```
 byte[] Image;
  Picasso.With(mContext).Load((Image)).Into(imageview1);
```

Now i'm getting error can not convert android graphics byte[] to anroid net uri

Is there any other way to convert it?

Comment: I guess “Image” is a variable of yours. How did you declare it?

Comment: Yes its a variable. I get image from sqlite.   foreach (var item in table)
                {
                    Image = item.ItemImg;
                   

                }

Comment: But you don’t need picasso to display a bitmap onto an imageView simply use imageView.setImageBitmap

Comment: I know but the problem is that i'm using imageview inside a listview adapter. So the problem is that my listview with images is very low performance also its increase my memory. Picasso it was very smooth in my listivew and manage very well memory thats why i want to use picasso.

Comment: Dude, save bytearray to file and give that file path to Picasso. Picasso.with(context).load("file://"+path)

Comment: If you wanna manage the memory in the right way use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView. I don’t think that introduce additionel filesystem I/O write and read to use Picasso should improve yuor performances...

Comment: Nice thought!  i will search it. if it is easy to make, send an example.

Comment: Both thought are good enough!

Comment: So you got advices and even an answer. You should give feedback on your findings to improve the quality of your question and to let other readers know what have you chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our messages I don't think that using Picasso to put your Bitmap in you ImageView it's the best solution for you.

If the main problem of your Application is a performance issue due to the use of a `ListView` to display a list of many images I suggest you to use a `RecyclerView` instead. Look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html).

If you still want to use Picasso to put your images on their ImageViews so I think that could be better not to store them directly on the `SQLite` database, but to store them on the phone storage and save on the `SQLite` database their filesystem `full path` (e.g. /storage/yourfolder/image1.png).

So you could use always a `RecyclerView` (the layout you always should choose to show a list of item due to its memory management) and in its ViewHodlder you could use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) to show images onto the ViewHolder ImageViews taken the images from the filesystem as Prafulla Malviya said.

As you know Picasso could display images from any Resouces, assets, files and content provider:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```